# .NET MEF DirectoryCatalog issue

Tags: excel, add-in, mef

I am developing Excel add-in and use MEF to provide extensibility. DirectoryCatalog works fine on my local drive, however when I deploy solution to the network drive composition silently fails. 
 In regular .exe application this problem can be resolved by adding "loadFromExternalSources=true" to "runtime" section of application configuration file, however for Excel add-in this file does not exist (and I can't add Excel.exe.config to the folder, containing Excel executable since this folder is read-only).  Is there any way to programmatically enable loadFromExternalSources behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to programmatically enable loadFromExternalSources behavior?

If you create a seperate [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w124b5fa.aspx) with [AppDomain.CreateDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aehss7y0.aspx), then you can pass a [AppDomainSetup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.aspx) which has a [ConfigurationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx) property.

However, I suppose that comvisible objects are normally created in the default appdomain so making the *new* AppDomain talk to Excel will probably be difficult. I guess it would involve shim classes in the default appdomain which pass calls through to the other appdomain.